# Having issue loading frontend on Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, database

I am running Magento2.3 on AWS m5.xlarge (ubuntu 18.04)

Backend is running pretty smooth, with page refreshes within 2-3 seconds, but frontend most of the time doesn't load and when it loads it takes around 3-5 minutes.

One thing I noticed is mysql taking high cpu usage around 250% (when ran top command) and overall 95% cpu.

I ran sqltuner command and did the necessary optimization as suggested by the command.

I checked by logging in mysql and ran

```
show full processlist;
```

but it only shows the above command.

Not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add `SetEnv MAGE_PROFILER "html"` in .htaccess in your project and check which process is taking too much time to load.

Comment: Is M 2.3 debug mode OFF? And PROD rather than DEV on? 
Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete SQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.